# What is the functionality of ## and %% in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash

```
disk="/dev/sda"
local dev_node=${disk##*/}
```

dev_node is assigned with "sda".

Also,

```
partition="/dev/sda3"
echo ${partition%%[0-9]*}
```

It returns /dev/sda and remove 3.

I did not understand the functionality of ##*/ and %%[0-9]*in the above commands. I tried searching but could not get enough information.

Please explain and provide any links to tutorial related to this.

Comment: `man bash` then `/##`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very good [manual / tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). What concerns your question:

> ${string##substring} Deletes longest match of $substring from **front** of
>   $string.

and

> ${string%%substring} Deletes longest match of $substring from **back** of
>   $string.

applied to your example: removing the longest substring matching `*/` from `/dev/sda` results in `sda`

Answer (score 2):

This procedure is commonly described as `parameter expansion`.

In your case `##` and `%%` are operators that extract part of the string.

`##` deletes longest match of defined substring starting at the start of given string.

`%%` does the same, except it starts from back of the string.

Good guide is [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables).